# Any idea why this is giving a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsarray, exc-bad-access

I have this line of code being called when the user taps a row on a table. It works at random and then it stops working all together giving a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I have NSZombieEnabled on, but it doesn't show anything.

```
[api make_call:@"update_privacy" api_objects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"], @"privacy_setting", indexPath.row, nil]];
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print your variables, which you aren't sure about value, in order to see what happend.

```
id username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 @"username",
                 username,
                 @"privacy_setting",
                 indexPath.row,
                 nil];

NSlog(@"%@ - %d - %@", username, indexPath.row, array);
[api make_call:@"update_privacy" api_objects:array];
```

Answer (score 4):

`indexPath.row` isn't an `NSObject`, you can't add if to the array.
Check that [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"] isn't returning nil.